# How to fix "$ is not defined" error when unit testing Jquery with Typescript using Mocha?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, jsdom

I am writing **Mocha** unit tests for **Typescript** code containing **Jquery**. I'm using **jsdom** for getting the document object. When I compile my TS code to JS and run the tests, it throws an error **[ReferenceError: $ is not defined]**.

My Typescript code is here

```
export function hello(element) : void {
    $(element).toggleClass('abc');
};
```

My unit test code is as follows:

```
import {hello} from '../src/dummy';

var expect = require('chai').expect;
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var document = jsdom.jsdom();
var window = document.defaultView;

var $ = require('jquery')(window);

describe('TEST NAME', () => {

    it('should run', (done) => {
        hello($('div'));
        done();
    });
});
```

When I run Mocha test it shows

```
    <failure message="$ is not defined"><![CDATA[ReferenceError: $ is not defined ...
]]></failure>
```

Also tried using *global.$ = require("jquery");* but does not work.

Comment: this is a bit unrelated but you should consider the built in functionality that angular provides for working with the dom. you shouldn't need jquery for dom manipulation.

Comment: For me, this problem surfaced as 'typescript TypeError: jQuery.Deferred is not a function' or 'typescript TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function', because I made the mistake of using an import * from jquery in a node.js environment, which doesn't work. If you're in that same situation, Louis' answer, or my own answer, will help you. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery has to be available globally because your script gets it from the global space. If I modify your code so that `var $ = require('jquery')(window);` is replaced by:

```
global.$ = require('jquery')(window);
```

then it works. Note the two calls: 1st to require `jquery`, then to build it by passing `window`. You could alternatively do:

```
global.window = window
global.$ = require('jquery');
```

If `window` is available globally, then there is no need to perform the double call as in the first snippet: jQuery just uses the globally available `window`.

You probably also want to define `global.jQuery` since some scripts count on its presence.

Here is a full example of a test file that runs:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/mocha/mocha.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/chai/chai.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/jsdom/jsdom.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./global.d.ts" />

import {hello} from './dummy';

import chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
import jsdom = require('jsdom');
var document = jsdom.jsdom("");
var window = document.defaultView;

global.window = window
global.$ = require('jquery');

describe('TEST NAME', () => {

    it('should run', (done) => {
        hello($('div'));
        done();
    });
});
```

The `typings` files are obtained the usual way using `tsd`. The file `./global.d.ts` fixes the issue you may get with setting new values on `global`. It contains:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      window: any;
      $: any;
    }
}
```

`dummy.js` was also modified like this:

```
declare var $: any;

export function hello(element) : void {
    $(element).toggleClass('abc');
};
```

Comment: I tried using global.$ but it said "$ is not a property of Global". Also tried (<any>global).$ and it said "$ is not a function"

Comment: I've used JSDom extensively but I'm not that familiar with Typescript so I wrote from a JSDom perspective mainly. I've updated my answer to add the Typescript-related changes that I made.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Louis :)

Comment: i used directly `(global as any).$ = require('jquery');` it worked without all the rest of the code

Answer (score 3):

You need to include jsdom and jQuery in Node first:

```js
npm install jsdom --save-dev
npm install jquery --save-dev
```

and then add this lines into your .js file where you are using jQuery

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM(`...`);
var jQuery = require('jquery')(window);

var example = (function($) {
 .....your jQuery code....
})(jQuery);

module.exports = example;
```

Comment: I kept getting error that JSDOM is not a constructor, happened at 'new JSDOM(`...`)"

Answer (score 1):

I found this question in 2020 and Louis got me pointing in the right direction. However, I found `jsdom-global` an easier alternative way of getting document working in Mocha.
I installed `jsdom-global` following the instructions at [jsdom-global](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global)

I used these lines to get jQuery and $ working as expected:

```
require('jsdom-global')();
global.window = window;
global.$ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = $;
```

Then this test passed with flying colours:

```
const assert = require("chai").assert;
function test(){
    return "test";
}
describe('Setting up global constants...', function () {
    describe('Libraries...', function () {
        it('jQuery and $ are present', () => {
            assert(jQuery !== undefined);
            assert($ !== undefined);
            assert($ === jQuery);
            assert($.isFunction(test));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to alter the global namespace type definition, you can still include jQuery, as following:

```
const globalAny:any = global;
const $ = globalAny.$ = require('jquery')(window);
```

The full initialization of jQuery then becomes:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = (new JSDOM());
const globalAny:any = global;
const $ = globalAny.$ = require('jquery')(window);
```

Answer (score -2):

As said, you should import jQuery properly: `import $ = require('jquery');`